# How to express (implicit conv: String => A) as a view bound

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicits, view-bound

I am asking myself what would be the view bound equivalent to

```
(implicit conv: String => A)
```

My first attempt was to simply declare the type parameter `A` as follows:

```
[String <% A]
```

But the Scala compiler complains with *"not found: type A"*.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you getting type A from? Does (implicit conv: String => A) work? Please post all the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a view bound. A view bound says that a type parameter `A` is bounded in that it can be viewed (converted to) as a type `B`. What you have inverted type and type parameter, so it doesn't qualify.

To make things more clear, a *bound* is a limit on a "free" type -- a type parameter. For example:

```
type A <: String // A has an upper bound
type A >: String // A has a lower bound
```

So a *view* bound is also a limit -- one imposed through a very different mechanism. As such, it can only be imposed on a type parameter, not on a type.

Surely, saying `String => A` must exist is also a kind of bound, but not one that has a name or syntactic sugar for.

Comment: That's a good explanation. I think Tim Friske was looking for an "inverted" view bound: `[A >% String]` (pseudo-code). Scala doesn't have this, just write out the implicit conversion by hand.

Answer (score 8):

-- *Revised post* --

The syntax `[B <% A]` actually binds a new type `B`. So

```
class Foo[A, String <% A]
```

is equivalent to

```
class Foo[A, String](implicit $conv: String => A)
```

where `String` is an arbitrary type parameter, not the class you're thinking of.

I think the named implicit conversion is probably your best option,

```
class Foo[A](implicit conv: String => A)
```

where now the type of `String` is not shadowed.

Summary: view bounds are useful as conversions *from* the introduced type parameter, not *to* the type parameter.

Comment: Thanks Lex and Kipton for your prompt reply. @Kipton: I thought it is feasible to declare the type parameter `A` with the view bound in one go. Something like `class Foo[String <% A]`. Isn't that possible?

Comment: You can do `class Foo[A, String <% A]`, but I just realized this is introducing a new type `String` that shadows the usual `String` class. I rewrote my answer.